# R How to compare Rows and Delete by Matching Strings

Tags: r

```
  Match Up       Date   Points  Opponent Points Reb Opponent Reb
Dal vs Den  8/16/2015       20               21  10           15
Den vs Dal  8/16/2015       21               20  15           10
```

I have a dataframe with sports data. However, I have two rows for every game due to the way that the data had to be collected. For example the two rows above are the same game, but again the data had to be collected twice for each game in this case: once for `Dal` and one for `Den`.

I'd like to find a way to delete duplicate games. I figure that one of my conditions to compare will have to be game date. How else would I be able to tell R that I would like for it to check to delete duplicate rows? I assume that I should be able to tell R to:

1. Check that game date matches
2. If game date match and if "Teams" match then delete duplicate. (Can this be done even though the strings are not an exact match, i.e. since `Den vs Dal` and `Dal vs Den` would not be a matching string?)
3. Move on to the next row and repeat until the end of the spreadsheet.
4. R would not need to check more than 50 rows down before moving on to the next row.
5. Is there a function to test for matching individual words? So for example I do not want to have to tell R: "If cell contains `Den`... Or "If cell contains `Dal` as this would involve too many teams. R needs to be able to check the cells for ANY value that could be in and then look to find out if the same value can be found as a string in later rows.

Please help.

Comment: I think the easiest would be to standardize your `Teams` variable - split on `"vs"`, alphabetize, then recombine. Then you should be able to do the standard `unique()` or `!duplicated()` approach (many examples on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Probably longer than it needs to be: `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); df %>% separate(Match.Up, c('team1', 'team2'), sep = ' vs ', remove = FALSE) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(teama = min(team1, team2), teamb = max(team1, team2)) %>% group_by(teama, teamb, Date) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-starts_with('team'))`

Comment: Thank you for your help it is much appreciated.